# Trouble with inserting JS variable into MySQL table with PHP with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am a pretty much a beginner to all of these technologies, I have been stuck all day on what I thought would be a fairly simple process. Basically, I'm trying to pass a parameter in a JS function through to my PHP code using AJAX, and then inserting the parameter into my database.

The JS function in my .html file.

```
    function pushData(paramData) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "databaseStuff.php",
        type: "post",
        data: paramData
        });
}
```

I wish to insert into my SQL table whatever I have put into the Parameters. For example the below code should create 3 new database entries. I have these hooked up to buttons in my actual project.

```
pushData('It is Wednesday');
pushData('My Dudes');
pushData('AHHHHHHH!');
```

databaseStuff.php

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "default", "testDB");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . 
$mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo $mysqli->host_info . "<br>";

$paramData = $_POST['paramData'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO testDBtable (Name, Text) VALUES ('Joe', '$paramData')";

?>
```

My PHP is successfully connecting to the MySQL DB since I am getting the proper 'localhost via TCP/IP' message, however, I am getting stuck on:

"Notice: Undefined index: paramData in C:\wamp64\www\databaseStuff.php on line 23

Help is appreciated! I am not concerned with SQL injection vulnerability as this code will never leave localhost.

Comment: You never query the `$sql` variable. You just create the string.

Comment: You're already using an API that supports **prepared statements** with bounded variable input, you should utilize parameterized queries with placeholders (prepared statements) to protect your database against [SQL-injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)!
 Get started with [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare) and [`mysqli_stmt::bind_param()`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-param).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing your Ajax data parameters like this

```
data: {
    'paramdata':paramdata
}
```

Also, you never actually queried your data.

```
mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
```

But with the error that you're getting, it's likely because of the ajax data parameters.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem with getting my data to POST over to the PHP file. My other problem was caused by the automatic Timestamp in my database not having a default value.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to correct your code, replace the AJAX query with this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "databaseStuff.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {'paramData': paramData}
});
```

However, you should not concatenate user input with sql query directly because of SQL injections, I suggest you to use parametrized queries. Here is [the PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) with explanation and examples

Comment: XSS attacks is more of a problem on output. On input, what you're probably thinking of, is SQL injection